# UWP Programatically change background image of XAML page c#

Tags: c#, image, xaml, background, uwp

I have been searching for a while and honestly I haven't solved this really simple issue. I have a flyout menu and I have attached an event to a flyout menu item. I want to change programmatically the background image of my XAML page when I select the item.

```
<Grid x:Name="main">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/bg_1.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

This is the default image I got as a background (the grid is basically the whole page).

The C# event code is here:

```
private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    main.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///MTG Life Counter/Assets/bg_2.jpg")) , Stretch = Stretch.None};
}
```

When I select the menu item instead of setting the image as background, it makes it white.

[Default background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKsoD.jpg)

I tested and it is not an issue of the image. I know that I am doing something like an obvious mistake but I am a bit new to UWP and I couldn't find a solution.

[Here is the blank background after I select to change it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtgiL.png)

Thanks for you time and sorry for the ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's a property called "BaseUri"... try adding it to your code.

make these changes:

```
    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        main.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/bg_2.jpg")), Stretch = Stretch.None };
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately the problem is still the same. Blank background. i also tried the UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes. I tried all the possbile combinations of those two answers

Comment: the UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute method has no use in UWP projects(it's a method from the wpf world)... you did add the image to your project right?

Comment: yes sure. It is doing the same even if i replace the default with the default image. If i replace bg_1.jpg(which works when i put the source in XAML) with bg_1.jpg dynamixally, it is putting a blank background again

Comment: well it sounds like a Path error, you could try using the file name instead of full path. also check the settings on your images in solution explorer.... build type setting especially.

Comment: I've made some changes to my answer, check it out.

Comment: Thank you! it was the path. Seems that it only needed the file rather the whole path.

Comment: glad I could help mate :)